# Can I use the scanner driver to scan directly to a file instead of importing into a program?

Tags: drivers, scanner

I have a Canon Lide210 scanner, and having just bought a new PC (Windows 10 64-bit), I'm trying to keep it clean. As usual, the scanner came with a whole pile of bloatware which I don't want.

I downloaded and installed just the scanner driver from [Canon's web site](http://www.canon.co.uk/support/consumer_products/products/scanners/lide_series/canoscan_lide_210.aspx?type=drivers&driverdetailid=tcm:14-831505&os=WINDOWS%2010%20(64-bit)&language=), which works fine if I want to scan into a program (such as an image editor).

Is there a way of scanning directly to a disk file, without installing more software?

Comment: Canon scanners require it be imported into a program before being saved, I have never found a way to get around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well what you ask for is possible. Just installing the printer/scanner driver enabled me to use the windows tools to scan a file to the computer. However the Windows software is pretty bad to be honest. If you really want to go that way:

Go to "devices and printers", right click on the installed printer (should appear in there) and click on 'start a new scan'. The rest is self explanatory. This doesnt use any software apart from the driver, which Windows itself installed on my system at least.

This worked under both windows 7 and 10 for me, with the only difference being the installing process of the driver (7-manually, 10-automatically).

BUT I would highly recommend using a software instead: For me 'NAPS 2' is the one of choice, because it's way more convenient and better than the windows tool, still pretty small and it enables you to save to pdf files directly and add successive scans together etc. (to add to that it's open source).

https://www.naps2.com/

Comment: That's absolutely brilliant, thanks! It does everything I want without the bloat. What's even better is that there's a standalone version that doesn't require installation, you can just download and run. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no.  The scanner itself doesnt have the internal software to interact with the computer itself.  In order convert a scanned document to a file, such as a PDF or TIFF, it must use the software installed on the computer.

There are network based scanners that have the ability to write directly to a file system, however they are more expensive.

Comment: Oh well, was worth asking. Do you know of any decent (preferably free) software that will allow me to scan directly to file, but without all the bloatware that comes with? Thanks

Comment: @Keltari, yes it is possible without further software. See my answer.